# Deleting library file from subversion in Android Studio

Tags: android, svn

I want to delete a library file from subversion.
The steps I follow are
1. Delete from my libs folder
2. Delete dependencies from property file
3. Then Synchronize to commit the change

The issue happening is I cant see the deleted file to commit while synchronizing. What am I missing? I need to delete this library file from Subversion. I am doing this through Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :-
1. Select parent folder and right click.
2. And click on commit button.